# Конструктор копирования в двусвязном списке

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! вопрос про конструктор копирования. Написал двусвязный список.
С конструктором копирования возникли трудности. Начну с деструктора. Деструктор удаляет память выделенную для каждого узла списка. Память выделяется в конструкторе(для головы списка) и в методах `Insert,PushFront,PushBack`. 
Итак перейдем к конструктору копирования. Нам необходимо выделить память под узел. Далее нужно скопировать все указатели в поля `_next` и `_prev` нашей копии. Но! Как только для объекта с которого мы копируем данные вызывается деструктор то все указатели (`_next` и `_prev`) у каждого узла уничтожаются а значит их нет и в нашей копии - отсюда ошибка! Подскажите как решить проблему? И целесообразно ли вообще в таком случае делать конструктор копирования? Благодарю за внимание

```
  template<class T>
  class LinkedList
  {
    public:
    struct Node //узел
    {
      ////
      T _value;
      Node* _next;//указатель на след. узел
      Node* _prev;//указатель на предыдущий узел
    };

    class Iterator :public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>
    {//тут все ясно
    public:
    ////
    private:
    ////
    };

    LinkedList();
   ~LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& right);
    Iterator Insert(Iterator wher, T value);
    Iterator PushFront(T value);
    Iterator PushBack(T value);
    /// методы///
    }

    template<class T>
    LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
    {

      Iterator begin = Begin();
      Iterator end = End();

      while (begin != end)
      {
        Node* tempNext = begin.GetNext();
        delete[]begin.GetNode();
        begin = tempNext;
      }

      delete[]_head;
    }

    template <class T>
    LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList& right)
    {
      _head = new Node[1];
      _head->_value = right._head->_value;
      _head->_next = right._head->_next;
      _head->_prev = right._head->_prev;
    }

  };
```

Comment: замечание : то есть когда вызывается деструктор для копии то он пытается очистить то что уже очищено деструктором оригинала и тут возникает ошибка

Comment: Ваш конструктор копирования должен копировать ноды, а не сохранять указатели на них. Выделение `new Node[1]` и удаление `delete[] delete[]begin.GetNode();` памяти массивом явно ни к чему.

Comment: пусть так, но как только вызывается деструктор оригинала то все рушиться

Comment: Как я уже написал выше, ваш конструктор копирования должен копировать ноды, а не сохранять указатели на них. т.е. вместо `_head->_next = right._head->_next;` и `_head->_prev = right._head->_prev;`  надо пробегаться по списку и создавать копию каждой ноды.

Comment: почему это delete[]begin.GetNode(); не нужно?? в методах Insert,PushBack,PushFront выделяется память динамически. Я не дописал код Linked List содердит еще указатели Node* _head,Node* _ptr; в конструкторе LinkedList выделяю память под "голову"-> далее при добавление элемента в методах Insert,.. снова выделяю память под узел

Comment: Не нужно выделять память массивом из одного элемента `new Node[1]` и удалять `delete[]`. Выделяйте и удаляйте память для отдельного элемента.

Comment: Хорошо,с этим разобрался. По копированию: нужно пробежать по оригиналу и создать новый список и такими же полями _value, но поля _next и _prev будут уже иметь "новые" адреса верно?

Comment: и в чем отличие в выделение памяти под один элемент массива от "еденичного" выделения памяти?

Comment: и если выделять память как new Node то вылезает ошибка

Comment: Какая ошибка? А выделять память под массив из одного элемента не стоит, так как при этом будет overhead на хранение (внутреннее) размера массива. Ну и вообще-то тут массив не нужен.

Comment: По копированию: нужно пробежать по оригиналу и создать новый список и такими же полями _value, но поля _next и _prev будут уже иметь "новые" адреса верно?